# I'm getting the error on Cpanel that I'm running php 7.4 yet when I run php -v I get 8.02

Tags: php, laravel

I've deployed a laravel app on cpanel. The app is working as expected on my local machine but on cpanel I'm getting the error below.

`Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.4.30. in /home4/peakcoke/public_html/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24`

When I run php -v I get 8.0.20.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check you cpanel configuration. It looks like it's configured for a different PHP Version. Console could use the default PHP installed on the system, while apps use a different one.

Comment: I see the highest version on Cpanel is 7.4

Comment: I think the problem here is that composer is configured to use a different php version then the default on cli. It's what @Sascha says check the cpanel settings and namely what the default php version is.

Comment: @WhiteFang On Cpanel the default is 7.4 and the highest as well. I can't configure it to 8. I think that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do a phpinfo(), what you get by running `php -v` from terminal is PHP CLI version.

Also, Cpanel usually comes with PHP Selector component that allows you to switch between different installed versions.

Comment: After doing ```dd(phpinfo());``` I get ```PHP Version 8.0.20```